# How to make css animation inside a button element smaller?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make css animation small and responsive but I seem to can't figure it out. I tried changing the main width from 80px to something smaller but it messes with the positions also. I have tried also setting the button to position absolute and the children to relative but didn't get the outcome I was looking for. If change the button size to be smaller it cuts off half of the animation instead of making shrinking its size to fit inside the button.

I'm trying to make it look similar to something like this!

[image]

```css
button {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.lds-facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-facebook div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  animation: lds-facebook 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1) infinite;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(1) {
  left: 8px;
  animation-delay: -0.24s;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 32px;
  animation-delay: -0.12s;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 56px;
  animation-delay: 0;
}

@keyframes lds-facebook {
  0% {
    top: 8px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 24px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div class="lds-facebook">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
  Processing
</button>
```

Comment: But so what is the desired result? Like what are you trying to do?

Comment: Usually, a button won't need to be responsive. You just need to set it to 100% width of parent element, it will work fine.

Comment: @FivePlyPaper I'm trying to make the button smaller with the CSS animation. I tried to make the button smaller but it cuts off half of the animation when doing so. Basically, I want the CSS animation to be in the center with the text right next to it.

Comment: @Raptor I'm trying to make the custom CSS animation responsive or small fixed size.

Comment: @AJJones So you want the animation to be smaller relative to the button? Or do you just want it all appearing in line?

Comment: @FivePlyPaper Both. Smaller and in line.

Comment: @AJJones so you want the animation to look like the size of periods next to processing? With the word in front?

Comment: @FivePlyPaper I just want to know how I can make the animation smaller. Its current size blows the button up making it way to big. Making it behind the work like periods could work also.

Comment: @AJJones well you have the button drawn in pixels so the size is absolute. What you want to do is use percentages making the button sizes relative to the size of its container

Comment: @AJJones My solution should fix your problem. Is that kind of what you were going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to what you did. I will modify it more but as you can see I changed all of your sizes to be percentages, that is, dependent on the size of the `.lda-facebook` div size. I also put the processing text into a div to allow it to be displayed in flex. If you want your stuff to be resizable you just need to base it all on relative size not absolute values.

**EDIT**

I also filled out the containers with the height and width making them proportional to their spaces.

```css
button {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
}

.lds-facebook {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
}


/* Made position relative, used margin-left for spacing.
   Also have them all equal width to fill the container    
*/
.lds-facebook div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 33%;
  background: #fff;
  animation: lds-facebook 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1) infinite;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.24s;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.12s;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

/* Set some margin to the text to give spacing
   and aligned it to the center.
*/
.proc-text {
   margin-left: 5%;
   align-self: center;
}

/* Changed to use 100% of the height to again fill out
   the entire container
*/
 
@keyframes lds-facebook {
  0% {
    top: 8%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 24%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div class="lds-facebook">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="proc-text">
      Processing
  </div>
</button>
```

### SMALLER VERSION

If the processing div is placed before then, naturally, it will come before.
I also shrunk the overall size which made the animation smaller but allowed for a nice compact look for the button.

```css
button {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
}

.lds-facebook {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
}


/* Made position relative, used margin-left for spacing.
   Also have them all equal width to fill the container    
*/
.lds-facebook div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 33%;
  background: #fff;
  animation: lds-facebook 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1) infinite;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.24s;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.12s;
}

.lds-facebook div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

/* Set some margin to the text to give spacing
   and aligned it to the center.
*/
.proc-text {
   margin-left: 5%;
   align-self: center;
}

/* Changed to use 100% of the height to again fill out
   the entire container
*/
 
@keyframes lds-facebook {
  0% {
    top: -8%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 16%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
<div class="proc-text">
      Processing
  </div>
  <div class="lds-facebook">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
</button>
```

Comment: Great! I see want you mean by making it proportional to their spaces now.

Comment: @AJJones Awesome glad I could help :). Yea a large part of CSS and responsive design is percentages. It is commonly bad practice to use absolute sizing because it can cause issues like you saw here. Always best to use percentages and relative sizing where possible!